# Center Text inside background image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a backgroundimage in a `<div>` element that has another `<div>` element with text inside it.
Since the text changes, I need to center it dynamically.
So far I have this, but it is still left aligned:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>3D Text</title>
<script> sets the text dynamically</script>
<style>

#Layer {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px; 
    position: absolute; 
    border-style: none;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
    }

#clock {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    color: black;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    float: left;
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
} 




</style>

</head>

<body onload="onLoad()">

        <div id="Layer"><img src="bg2.png" class="stretch"/></div> 

            <div  id="clock">
                <script language="JavaScript">setText(); setInterval("setText()", 1000 )</script>
            </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clock div is not inside the Layer div.

Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>3D Text</title>
<script> sets the text dynamically</script>
<style>

#Layer {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
    border-style: none;
    background-image: url(bg2.png);
    }

#clock {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}




</style>

</head>

<body onload="onLoad()">

        <div id="Layer">

            <div  id="clock">
              12:00PM
            </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Totally did the job. Except it has to be 'background-image: url(bg.png);'

Comment: Since my background image is 960 x 640 pixels I also nee dto reduce it by 50% in size to fit it in my "Layer"-div. Is there a CSS property to do that?

Comment: background-size is the property I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `float: left`. A floating element only uses the space it needs.

You will have to set the `width` property on `#clock` to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to a have a width set for your div for it to align the text